# How to populate missing match value

Tags: r

I am using the match function but when a match is not found I want text to be returned:

INPUT

```
Map<-c("hi","bye")
r<-data.frame(x= c("bye","hi",3909090))
r$y<- c(100,200,300)
r
r$MatchColumn  <- Map[ match(r$x,Map)  ]
r
is.na(r$MatchColumn)
```

OUTPUT

```
> r
        x   y
1     bye 100
2      hi 200
3 3909090 300
> r$MatchColumn  <- Map[ match(r$x,Map)  ]
> r
        x   y MatchColumn
1     bye 100         bye
2      hi 200          hi
3 3909090 300        <NA>  ####################### YOU CAN SEE THE NA HERE
> is.na(r$MatchColumn)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I want r to look like this:

```
> r
        x   y MatchColumn
1     bye 100         bye
2      hi 200          hi
3 3909090 300        Missing Data
```

I want thinking to use is.na(r$MatchColumn) somehow any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
r$MatchColumn[is.na(r$MatchColumn)] <- 'Missing Data'
```